# How do mesh coordinates and draw coordinates relate to each other in ggez library?

Tags: rust, game-development

When creating a line, a list of points is passed, but `graphics::draw` expects X/Y coordinates:

```rust
let (origin, dest) = (Point::new(0.0, 0.0), Point::new(0.0, 0.0));
let line = graphics::Mesh::new_line(ctx, &[origin, dest], 2.0, graphics::WHITE)?;
graphics::draw(ctx, &line, (Point2::new(0.0, 0.0),))?;
```

For rectangles, `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` are passed when creating a rectangle but `graphics::draw` expects X/Y coordinates:

```rust
let rectangle = graphics::Mesh::new_rectangle(
    ctx,
    graphics::DrawMode::fill(),
    [0.0, 0.0, 30.0, 30.0].into(),
    graphics::WHITE,
)?;
graphics::draw(ctx, &rectangle, (Point::new(0.0, 0.0),))?;
```

Why are both coordinates needed?

Comment: If I had to guess, the point you pass gets used as the coordinate system for drawing the other objects (basically the x,y of the point is added to the x,y values of everything else). Have you experimented at all?

Comment: Yes i just did and it seems mesh xy coordinates is useful for things like rectangle centering

Comment: If you've found the answer to your question, you can actually post it in the answer field below so other people can benefit

Comment: https://github.com/ggez/ggez/issues/659#issuecomment-513786990

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the author of the ggez library](https://github.com/ggez/ggez/issues/659#issuecomment-513786990):

> The difference is whether it's in the mesh's coordinate space or in the screen's coordinate space. Sorry for the tautological answer, let me see if I can do better...
>
> When you create the Mesh, imagine that you're drawing the points on a piece of transparent graph paper. That's the mesh coordinate system. Then when you call `graphics::draw()` you put that over another piece of graph paper, and the coordinates you pass to `draw()` is how much you offset the two by. But it's not just an offset, `draw()` takes options that can rotate, scale etc. the mesh's coordinate system. If you just create your mesh so that it's centered at `50,50` and then rotate it, it will by default rotate around its `0,0` point and not the center of the mesh. If you create your mesh so it's centered at its `0,0` coordinate, by default rotating it or scaling it will start from its own center. The `DrawParam::offset()` parameter can control where the "center" point is, but it's still kind of a pain.
>
> So you can achieve exactly the same thing with both methods, but I'd say that `draw()` is better for position manipulation.